# How to access variables from super?

Tags: python

I need to get at some variables in a method called with `super` I would really like to do this instead of subclassing and then redefining the method...

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        x = 1

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        print x
        super(SubFoo, self).bar(*args, **kwargs)
```

but I am getting `object has no attribute 'request'`

I tried using self as well but it would not work

Comment: Is that the whole script?

Comment: well my real example is on a much bigger class, but this is boiled down to the root problem

Comment: What's the whole error?

Comment: By looking at the error message, the problem probably lies at a place where it is written `self.request` (or at least where `request` appears), which does not appear in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, either make x an instance attribute, or return x in your `Foo.bar` method. Below example makes use of assigning x as an instance attribute:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        self.x = 1


class SubFoo(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        super(SubFoo, self).bar()
        print(self.x)


s = SubFoo()
s.bar()
```

The above execution will output `1`.

Alternatively, you can do a `return x` from your `Foo.bar` method, but remember, then that means you need to handle this return somehow. So, you need to make sure you get the return from your `super` call:

```
    def bar(self):
        res = super(SubFoo, self).bar()
        print(res)
```